# What is the best way to serialize, return and consume complex C# object from an MVC3 app?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

Here's my situation: I have an MVC3 app that has some very complex C# objects, and those get rendered to a views in this application. However, I have a new requirement: a console application (that I am also writing) will run under a scheduler, and it needs to pull these objects from this MVC3 app, and then do something else with these complex objects.

Since I have control over both apps, I can share a library of the complex objects between them. All of these objects are marked [Serializable]. However, I cannot figure out an easy way to serialize these objects and send them from the MVC3 app to the Console app.

I tried simple JavaScriptSerializer and using the HttpClient to read the string, then deserialize it on the console-app end of things, but unfortunately it doesn't deserialize the data correctly. Everything is null. I can inspect the string on a breakpoint when it arrives at the console app, and all the data is there, in the string, but it just doesn't get de-serialized correctly.

Is there an easier way to do this? I don't care what the serialization method is. The data doesn't have to be passed as JSON and no other application but mine is going to consume these objects. But so far I can't figure out the easiest way to produce/consume these objects.

I know I can go down the whole "create a web service contract" and use data annotations route, but I was hoping there was an easier, less time-consuming way of doing it.

Comment: Even Microsoft recommends to use the JSON.NET package instead of `JavaScriptSerializer`, have you tried that? Does your type contain circular dependencies? Can you post an example of the "Complex" data? Using JSON.NET you don't have to share libraries, you can deserialize to anonymous objects.

Comment: If your objects are mere models, i.e. they have no behaviour, I think XML or JSON is the way to go

Comment: What you describe sounds like it should work.  However without seeing some code, we can't possibly tell you why it isn't working.  For example, provide your model, the console code trying to deserialize the JSON string and the actual JSON string and the relevant MVC code.

Comment: My models have behavior.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33550336/96780) is the fifth [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers): 33550336. It may be the last perfect number we ever see on Stack Overflow, since the sixth one is 8589869056.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

### Server-Side

```
string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourComplexObject);
// Send the string to the client...
```

---

### Client-Side

In the client, you don't even have to know the deserialized object's type, you can take advantage of [anonymous objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) and [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx):

```
string serializedObject = // ... Fetch from server
dynamic complexObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedObject);
// ...
string id = complexObject.UserId;
```

---

**P.S.**: Please note that the object's methods or state is not going to get serialized, only the public properties are.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Since I already have the shared library, I was able to use this call: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyComplexObject>(serializedObject); Perfect. Thanks Matias!

Comment: @ChrisHolmes No problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Can your action just return your object? If so, your client code would look something like (using HttpClient)

```
var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
var myObj = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
```

Comment: I don't have ReadAsAsync<T> on that method. I am only seeing ReadAsByteArrayAsync, ReadAsStreamAsync, or ReadAsStringAsync.